# Binding to a property of a property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, nested

I'm very new to WPF and it's really throwing me for a loop. I'm trying to bind to a member of a member on a custom UserControl:

**The control:**

```
<UserControl
...
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
>
    <Grid x:Name="TestControlRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="TestControl" Margin="8">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Label Name="TitleLabel" Content="{Binding Path=esmTest.testName, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**The code-behind of the control:**

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty esmTestProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("esmTest", typeof(ESMTest), typeof(TestControl));
    public ESMTest esmTest
    {
        get { return (ESMTest)GetValue(esmTestProperty); }
        set { SetValue(esmTestProperty, value); }
    }
    public TestControl(ESMTest theTest)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        esmTest = theTest;
    }
    ...
}
```

**ESMTest class**

```
public class ESMTest : DependencyObject
{
    ...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty testNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("testName", typeof(string), typeof(ESMTest));
    public string testName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(testNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(testNameProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

When I run this I don't get any content in the label. What am I missing here?

Also, I'm finding it very difficult to find good sources of information about WPF, particularly databinding. I can either find super basic tutorials or stack exchange posts about how to fix very particular problems. I would love a comprehensive article on the nitty-gritty of databinding and DependencyObjects in WPF so that I can get a complete picture of how this stuff works and the many different ways I might use this. Can anyone recommend a good resource?

Comment: Because `DataContext` of `Grid` is set to **string _TestControl_**. Remove it and see if it helps.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that... that must have been when I was still learning how DataContext works. It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up comments in this line

```
<Grid ... DataContext="TestControl">
```

You overwrite `DataContext` set above with a **string *TestControl***. If you would remove that your bindings should work fine